# Reading JMeter Timestamp

Tags: jmeter, timestamp, listener

I am trying to save all the details of the requests and responses in a file by using Listener ***View Results Tree*** and ***Simple Data Writer***.
When I open the results in notepad;

[image: what does the ts Label(highlighted with yellow) mean?]

Does **ts** mean Time Stamp and if yes how to read those numbers?

Comment: You just want to see the date ? you have online converters as https://www.epochconverter.com/

Comment: No, I want to see the time as well and by the way what format is this?

Comment: it shows also time

Comment: How to read it?

Answer (score 1):

- `Does ts mean Time Stamp` - yes it does
- `how to read those numbers` - it's milliseconds since the beginning of [Unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)

---

Moreover

- If you want these timestamps to be more in human-readable form you can add the next line to *user.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

  ```
   jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS
  ```

  and upon JMeter restart you will start seeing these timestamps as `2021/02/15 13:56:39.288`

  See [Configuring JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter) user manual chapter for more details
- You should not use Listeners for anything apart from test development and debugging, [listeners don't add any value and just consume the valuable resources](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing/), all the metrics can be found in the .jtl results file and if you're not happy with its default configuration it can be [amended just like the timestamp](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config)

Comment: Thank you! How can I fetch that ,jtl results file?

Comment: If you [run JMeter in command-line non-GUI mode](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/) like `jmeter -n -t /path/to/your/test.jmx -l /path/to/results.jtl` this `-l` parameter defines the location of the [jtl results file](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/JMETER/JtlFiles) and its **you** who decides where it should go.